# Why is the DOM not updating with state change in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update the font size of an element using a slider. When I slide the slider, the value changes and I can successfully store that into my state using `e.target.value`.

But the problem is the font size does not update as I expect. I can't figure out why?

Here is my React component code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [slider, setSlider] = useState(20);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSlider( e.target.value );
    console.log(slider);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
        <label style={ { fontSize: slider } }>Example range</label>
        <input 
          type="range" 
          className="custom-range" 
          id="customRange1"
          min="10" 
          max="30"
          defaultValue={slider}
          onChange={handleChange}
        /> 
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57688970/9187227

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you replace `defaultValue` with the `value` prop, and update your `<label>` elements `style` as shown below, then your component will work as expected:

```
function App() {
  const [slider, setSlider] = useState(20);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSlider( e.target.value );
    console.log(slider);
  }

  return (<div className="container">
        {/* Format valid value for fontSize property */ }
        <label style={{ fontSize: `${slider}px` }}>Example range</label>

        {/* Supply slider state via value prop rather than defaultValue */ }
        <input 
          type="range" 
          className="custom-range" 
          id="customRange1"
          min="10" 
          max="30"
          value={slider}
          onChange={handleChange}
        /> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

See [this link for relevant documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) discussing form/inputs elements that have a `value` prop specified (referred to as "Controlled components")

Comment: This is working because of style={{ fontSize: ` ${slider}px ` }} and not because of replacing defaultValue with value. Default value is for initial rendering only, after user touches slider, it has no after effects.

Answer (score 5):

You miss the unit here,

```
<label style={ { fontSize: `${slider}px` } }>Example range</label>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jhpjsb)

Answer (score 1):

`const [slider, setSlider] = useState(20);`

Here, you are assigning **Number** to slider and then updating it with **string** `(console.log(typeof e.target.value))` i.e. you are changing data type of something, which is not good practice to code. Because it may affect your code, if you are dependent on it(slider) at more than one places, your program may break and you would never find such mistakes, follow good coding practices.

Try using `setSlider(Number(e.target.value));` instead of `setSlider(e.target.value);`

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-black-x6uzx

Answer (score 0):

Example range
If you mention without unit it will take the bydefault fontsize.In your case the fontsize is updating in slider but that is not usable because unit is missing.